# How can I use isRecord() and RecordComponent[] in Record Java?

Tags: java

I'm reading about record java on the [official documents](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/records.html#GUID-6699E26F-4A9B-4393-A08B-1E47D4B2D263)

At the last of the article, the author said:

> The class java.lang.Class has two methods related to record classes:
>
> - RecordComponent[] getRecordComponents(): Returns an array of java.lang.reflect.RecordComponent objects, which correspond to the record class's components.
> - boolean isRecord(): Similar to isEnum() except that it returns true if the class was declared as a record class.

So, I tried to find some tutorial or any guides help me understand more clearly about these concept but according to my understanding, I didn't find any useful

I have tried to do a example like this, but it not works

```
public record HelloWorld(String name) {

}
...
...
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloWorld h = new HelloWorld("Manh");
        System.out.println(h);

        System.out.println(h.isRecord());
//        RecordComponent
    }
}
```

Could you provide some examples to help me understand about these two APIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those methods are meant to be used on the `Class` object, i.e. `HelloWorld.class` in this case.

```java
record HelloWorld(String name, int n) {
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var clazz = HelloWorld.class;
        System.out.println(clazz.isRecord()); // true
        for (var comp : clazz.getRecordComponents()) {
            System.out.println(comp.getName() + " " + comp.getType());
        }
        /*
        name class java.lang.String
        n int
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: [Online Demo](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZA7jsIwEIZFm1OMqBwBrlcgKpptNgVBolhRmMRERo4d2ZNIYZWTbEMBl9rT7OTBq2AseaTxP9-M_9_LUVTifL6WeJh9_I2iotxrlUCihffwJZSBnwAohrpHgZQqq1LI6ZXF6JTJvncgXObDQdxGJVxLOZ1gCZ9Sa7u1Tqe8Ay_uqrj2KHNuS-QFgVAb1jVx5dcysS5lYfhQH6wD1oFtXsC85_NMYq9dUdUaadBT19Mq7waRvG2ORC5ZCBMY05nArbypC_kyvQn6uwlcN-7pW4MNYAg1BcKDaRdoelsHd28u_wM)

Answer (score 3):

> *"... So, I tried to find some tutorial or any guides help me understand more clearly about these concept but according to my understanding, I didn't find any useful ..."*

The documentation is referring to the *[Class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html)* *class*.

You can obtain a static reference, via the *.class* syntax.

```java
Class<HelloWorld> c = HelloWorld.class;
```

Or, an instance reference, via the *[Object#getClass](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#getClass())* method.

```java
HelloWorld h = new HelloWorld("Manh");
Class<?> c = h.getClass();
```

From here, you can access the *getRecordComponents* and *isRecord* methods.

```java
c.getRecordComponents()
```

```java
c.isRecord()
```